# No idea how to use popt library

Tags: c++, c, linux

All:

Thanks for help.

I am new to C option parsing, for now, what I want is to use popt library to parsing the each argument and prnit them out.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <popt.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){

        char* dt1;
        char* dt2;

        struct poptOption {
               const char * longName; /* may be NULL */
               char shortName;        /* may be ’\0’ */
               int argInfo;
               void * arg;            /* depends on argInfo */
               int val;               /* 0 means don’t return, just update flag */
               char * descrip;        /* description for autohelp -- may be NULL */
               char * argDescrip;     /* argument description for autohelp */
            };
        struct poptOption optionsTable[]={
            {"start",'s',POPT_ARG_STRING,dt1,'s',"The date format should like YYYY-MM-DD.",0},
            {"end",'e',POPT_ARG_STRING,dt2,'e',"The date format should like YYYY-MM-DD.",0},
            //~ POPT_AUTOHELP
            //~ {NULL,0,0,NULL,0}
            };

        poptContext optCon;
        optCon = poptGetContext (0, argc, argv, optionsTable, 0);

            const char* portname = poptGetArg(optCon);
        cout<<portname<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I got error llike:

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’
>   test.cpp:27: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
>   test.cpp:27: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
>   test.cpp:30: error: cannot convert ‘main(int, const char**)::poptOption*’ to ‘const poptOption*’ for argument ‘4’ to ‘poptContext_s* poptGetContext(const char*, int, const char**, const poptOption*, unsigned int)’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be defining the struct poptOption in your program. That struct should be defined for you in the popt include file. Try removing that struct definition.

Note, I think you also need to uncomment this line:

```
    //~ {NULL,0,0,NULL,0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this warning is being reported is a feature of the C language, but the mistake in the code is due to how you are attempting to use popt.

The types (char*) and (const char*) in C are different types.  One is not really the other, and while C allows assignment from one type to another without blowing up, any decent C compiler will give you a warning.  You can hide the warnings with a type cast, but it's generally a bad idea.

A C-style string is of the type (const char*), and you are assigning it to the field `descrip` in poptOption which is defined as a (char*).  This raises a compiler warning because now, someone who reaches into that memory by following the reference from the `optionsTable` array could attempt to change the contents of the string.  That's an odd thing to allow, considering the string is defined as a constant.  That's why you get the warning.

The mistake in your code is that you are using popt incorrectly, with your own definition of the `poptOption struct`.  If you look within [the file that you include (popt.h)](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/anon-proxy/00.02.39/popt_8h_source.html) on line 55 you will see the `poptOption struct`, as it is defined by the popt authors.  It is:

```
struct poptOption {
    /*@observer@*/ /*@null@*/ const char * longName;    /* may be NULL */
     char shortName;         /* may be '\0' */
    int argInfo;
     /*@shared@*/ /*@null@*/ void * arg;          /* depends on argInfo */
    int val;                /* 0 means don't return, just update flag */
     /*@shared@*/ /*@null@*/ const char * descrip;       /* description for autohelp -- may be NULL */
    /*@shared@*/ /*@null@*/ const char * argDescrip;    /* argument description for autohelp */
};
```

or removing comments

```
struct poptOption {
    const char * longName;
    char shortName;
    int argInfo;
    void * arg;        
    int val;              
    const char * descrip;   
    const char * argDescrip; 
};
```

and you clearly see that even the authors expected a (const char *), and not the (char *) you defined.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin, I finally find the problem is I redefine the struct potOption.